# Postprocessing multiple BE form controls in FormEngine into a single field with custom RenderType

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

A TCA field is meant to contain the combination of several options. I created a new RenderType to display 5 select boxes. Now I need some post processing to combine the values into a single value for the (hidden) field.

What is the best/easiest way to add this postprocessing to the custom FormEngine node in a way that it can access all the form elements that belong to this single TCA field?

Comment: Two possibilities. Either you combine these values into one string using the results of the select boxes (e.g. resulting in `1-2-3-4-5`) by using JavaScript - you might want to look into DatePicker for the backend forms which is also transforming values. Alternativ is to pre-process data when it's send to `DataHandler` and combine arbitrary values into one string for the field that is registered in TCA - since `DataHandler` requires to have those fields to be configured in TCA.

Comment: @OliverHader I was looking for some place in code (PHP/JS) to hook into just before the form is submitted. I guess I need to write so JS that monitors changes in any of the elements and combine the values.